# store duration in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, create-table

I am getting source data with duration between 2 timestamps as

```
Duration            Start date          End date        Start station
14h 26min. 2sec.    12/31/2010 23:49    1/1/2011 14:15  10th & U St NW (31111)
```

how can I import this data ( which is in CSV file ) in Teradata database to store duration in correct data type, so that I can match it properly with the difference between start and end data?

Please help in correct approach here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the duration always including hours and minutes? What's the maximum duration? How are start&end formatted, there's no seconds in your example, but in duration?

Comment: @dnoeth : yes sir, I have asked this to source system that no seconds are there in the start and end date they will add it, please consider seconds as of now. Data includes fields like 23h 32min. 8sec. and fields like 0h 0min. 4sec. with 'h' 'min.' and 'sec.' included with '.' and yes data has '0' for no value with h, min sec always included. –

Answer (score 2):

That's quite tricky.

A pure SQL based solution (without features of your ETL-tool) needs to generate data which can be safely casted.

This will modify your duration into a format which can be passed to `to_dsinterval` by removing unneccessary characters besides `HMS` (target column should be defined as `INTERVAL HOUR(4) TO SECOND(0)`)

```
Cast(to_dsinterval('PT'||Upper(OTranslate(duration, ' in.ec', ''))) AS INTERVAL HOUR(4) TO SECOND(0))
```

Your input timestamps show single digit day/month, which Teradata doesn't support (don't aks why), the RegEx adds those missing zeroes (when the seconds are missing remove the `:ss` part of the format):

```
Cast(RegExp_Replace(start_date, '\b([0-9])\b', '0\1') AS TIMESTAMP(0) Format 'mm/dd/yyyyBhh:mi:ss')
```

Finally pass duration & timestamps as VarChars and apply the Casts during Insert.

Comment: @doneth: worked like expected and learned much digging into this to_dsinterval function. Thanks again.